# upload multiple files to firebase storage issues

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

i am working on a cooking android app where firebase is the backend, i need to upload multiple images of a recipe in firebase stoarge and then store the downloadurl into firebase database.

i managed to upload the files into firebase  but i am having some trouble to get the downloadUrl of these files.
i have created an array of promises to upload the files and i had created another array to store the url of each file which i get when it finishes the uploading task.

here is my  code

```
 var promises = [];
 for (var i=0 ;i< prepaImages.length;i++) 
            {
                //alert(prepaImages[i].name);

              var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("receipes"+"/"+category+"/"+title+"/"+uploadTime+prepaImages[i].name );
             var uploadTask = storageRef.put(prepaImages[i]);
              promises.push(uploadTask);

              uploadTask.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
              var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                $("#prepaImageUploadprogress").html(Math.round(percentage)+"%");
                $("#prepaImageUploadprogress").attr("style", "width:"+percentage+"%");


                }, error => { alert(error) }, () => {
                    uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
                        //prepaImagesUrl+="+"+downloadURL;
                       prepaImagesUrl.push(downloadURL);
                       });
});
```

the problem is  i am getting an array of the length of the number of uploaded files minus one (the legnth it should be equal to the number of uploaded files) and it has the same value (the same downloadurl) 
. any help will be appreciated
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with the promisies. I suggest you to use `Promise.all` and await. Therefore your code will be more reliable. Here is my solution to multiple file upload (adapt to your variable names):

```
const array = Array.from({ length: prepaImages.length }, (value, index) => index);
const uploadedImages = await Promise.all(array.map(async index => {
  const image = prepaImages[index];
  const metadata = { contentType: image.type };
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`receipes/${category}/${title}/${uploadTime}${prepaImages[i].name}`);
  const uploadTask = storageRef.put(image, metadata);
  const url = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
      const percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      $('#prepaImageUploadprogress').html(`${Math.round(percentage)}%`);
      $('#prepaImageUploadprogress').attr('style', `width: ${percentage}%`);
    }, error => reject(error),
    async () => {
      const downloadUrl = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      resolve(downloadUrl);
    });
  });
  return { name: image.name, url };
}));
```

The `uploadedImages` will contains an array with the image names and download urls. You can make this without await of course, but I prefer this way.

UPDATE:
Here is my own code (without error handling) to achieve this, also, I need to mention that I'm using this with react, redux and using the firebase, firestore wrapper for redux `redux-firestore` and `react-redux-firebase` but these are just wrappers:

```
export const addNewWork = work => async (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore  }) => {
  const { files, ...restWork } = work;
  const firebase = getFirebase();
  const firestore = getFirestore();
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  const array = Array.from({ length: files.length }, (value, index) => index);
  const uploadedFiles = await Promise.all(array.map(async index => {
    const file = files[index];
    const metadata = { contentType: file.type };
    const uploadTask = storageRef.child(`works/${file.name}`).put(file, metadata);
    const url = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', () => {}, error => reject(error), async () => {
      const downloadUrl = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        resolve(downloadUrl);
      });
    });
    return { name: file.name, url };
  }));

  await firestore.collection('works').add({
    ...restWork,
    image: uploadedFiles[0], // Use only one image for the clean example
    createdAt: new Date()
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. but it seems not working neither, it returns an empty array,
 after the "return { name: file.name, url };" i tried to save the array to the database but it is not working, it gives an empty array

Comment: The images are comes from an input field? This exact same code working one of my project perfectly well :\

Comment: Maybe check again the code, I've made a few mistake whith variable names when renamed them to your use case :\

Comment: yes yes i had corrected the typos and the variable names already, but the it didn't work, for the upload to the database should i do it outside the "await Promise.all(array.map(async index => {" or inside it, it seems didn't work for both cases for me

Comment: if possible could you give me the working code you have may be i could figure what i am missing please

Comment: I've added to my code to the answer, I hope you could use that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190832/discussion-between-knightburton-and-harounbest).